# What instrument should I double with clarinet?

Tags: clarinet, march

I have been playing clarinet for several years now and am looking for a good instrument to play as well. I have considered flute, oboe and saxophone. Any others I should consider and/or what do you recommend to have not-too-extreme changes in embouchure, fingering, and breathing? I play in marching band so I need a instrument suitable for that.

Comment: Oboe stands out as very different in fingering and embouchure from clarinet and your other options. Also bass clarinet and Eb clarinet are other options to consider.